# Android how to automatically accept bluetooth files?

Tags: java, android

Is there any way to automatically accept bluetooth file transfer requests from paired devices on android,  or automatically establish a connection with available paired devices? I know it might be dangerous to automatically accept all files but I need it for my app.

Comment: I have no idea, but once paired this shouldn't be much of a security issue in my opinion. I automatically connect a keyboard to a laptop every day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. Just open a `BluetoothSocket` with the `UUID` of the other device you want to connect to. Then you can read the bytes from the stream and handle them in the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

Pls provide more information about what you want to do.

Bluetooth connections have several problems, one is that after a timestamp the bluetooth is no longer available for you to detect. Unless u intend to constantly turn on the bluetooth visibility that is not going to work.

Answer (score 0):

I created a helper app that runs on Rooted Devices.

Please visit [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49379762/8614565) for more information.