# Programmatically Auto Accept Incoming Bluetooth Files

Tags: android, bluetooth, permissions

I am trying to find a way to have a tablet basically auto-accept/give permission to accept an incoming Bluetooth Share file transferred from a laptop to my Nexus Android device. Since the Android bluetooth system itself does not support this feature, I was wondering if this could be done programmatically using an Android application that listened for the notification and accepted it for me.

Comment: This shouldn't be possible because it was a security issue. Would you like any app to be able to accept bluetooth files without your approval?

Comment: If you have rooted device it may be possible using Xposed framework.

Comment: Did you root your phone?

Answer (score 2):

**MUCH EASIER WAY**

If you have a rooted device and use XPosed Framework, your goal can be achieved **much easier.**

You **Need not implement your own bluetooth server nor kill the original BT service, which are very bothering!!!**

[xposed tutorial link](https://github.com/rovo89/XposedBridge/wiki/Development-tutorial).

Try this code.

```
import android.util.*;
import de.robv.android.xposed.*;
import de.robv.android.xposed.callbacks.XC_LoadPackage.*;

import static de.robv.android.xposed.XposedHelpers.findAndHookMethod;

public class Tutorial implements IXposedHookLoadPackage
{

    private String TAG="TUTORIAL";
    public void handleLoadPackage(final LoadPackageParam lpparam) throws Throwable {
        if (!lpparam.packageName.equals("com.android.bluetooth"))
        {
            Log.i(TAG,"Not: "+lpparam.packageName);
            return;
        }
        Log.i(TAG,"Yes "+lpparam.packageName);  

        findAndHookMethod("com.android.bluetooth.opp.BluetoothOppManager", lpparam.classLoader, "isWhitelisted", String.class,new XC_MethodHook() {
                @Override
                protected void beforeHookedMethod(MethodHookParam param) throws Throwable {
                    Log.v(TAG,"HOOK DONE");
                    param.setResult(true); /* you can compare the sender address(String) with your computer and determine if you return true or just allow the original method to be called after this returns.*/

                }
            });

    }
}
```

I tested and it **works fine:)**

**Links**

[Dropbox link of the auto accepting app](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9fuviv2seahf8jf/app.apk?dl=0)

[Dropbox link of the project files (zip)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ttl2uqcnoysdwge/auto-accept.zip?dl=0)

[Xposed apk site](http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.installer)

[Towelroot site to root your phone](https://towelroot.com)

**Background(Original answer)**

As I commented above, you bay be able to, and I tried and succeeded in blocking (though not receiving) with this code.

```
import android.util.*;
import de.robv.android.xposed.*;
import de.robv.android.xposed.callbacks.XC_LoadPackage.*;
import java.io.*;

import static de.robv.android.xposed.XposedHelpers.findAndHookMethod;

public class Tutorial implements IXposedHookLoadPackage
{

    private String TAG="TUTORIAL";
    public void handleLoadPackage(final LoadPackageParam lpparam) throws Throwable {
        if (!lpparam.packageName.equals("com.android.bluetooth"))
        {
            Log.i(TAG,"Not: "+lpparam.packageName);
            return;
        }
        Log.i(TAG,"Yes "+lpparam.packageName);  

        findAndHookMethod("com.android.bluetooth.opp.BluetoothOppService", lpparam.classLoader, "startSocketListener", new XC_MethodHook() {
                @Override
                protected void beforeHookedMethod(MethodHookParam param) throws Throwable {
                    Log.v(TAG,"HOOK DONE");
                    param.setResult(null);
                }

            });

    }
}
```

The code above hooks the method `startListenerSocket()` of `com.android.bluetooth.BluetoothOppService` and prevents the original method from being called by the line `param.setResult(null);`

Refer to [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Bluetooth/+/eclair-release/src/com/android/bluetooth/opp/BluetoothOppService.java) to see the full code of `com.android.bluetooth.BluetoothOppService.java` and you will understand the operation.

And the code you can start from is shown below.

```
import android.util.*;
import de.robv.android.xposed.*;
import de.robv.android.xposed.callbacks.XC_LoadPackage.*;

import static de.robv.android.xposed.XposedHelpers.findAndHookMethod;

public class Tutorial implements IXposedHookLoadPackage
{

    private String TAG="TUTORIAL";
    public void handleLoadPackage(final LoadPackageParam lpparam) throws Throwable {
        if (!lpparam.packageName.equals("com.android.bluetooth"))
        {
            Log.i(TAG,"Not: "+lpparam.packageName);
            return;
        }
        Log.i(TAG,"Yes "+lpparam.packageName);  

        findAndHookMethod("com.android.bluetooth.opp.BluetoothOppObexServerSession", lpparam.classLoader, "onPut", new XC_MethodHook() {
                @Override
                protected void beforeHookedMethod(MethodHookParam param) throws Throwable {
                    Log.v(TAG,"HOOK DONE");
                    Class c=param.thisObject.getClass();
                }

            });

    }
}
```

This code hooks the `onPut` method of `com.android.bluetooth. BluetoothOppObexServerSession` linked [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Bluetooth/+/eclair-release/src/com/android/bluetooth/opp/BluetoothOppObexServerSession.java). I either am newbie to xposed framework but I hope my answer helped.

I had the same issues you asked and partially solved the problem by implementing my custom OBEX server and manually / programmatically(with `ps|grep` and `su kill pid`) killing the native BluetoothOppService. But I will either try the idea of hooking and directly executing my code.

And to help you customize OBEX server session I post my implementation below.

```
    @Override
    public int onPut(Operation op)
    {
        if (D)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "onPut " + op.toString());
        }
        HeaderSet request;
        String name, mimeType;
        Long length;
        String extension=null;// type;
        int obexResponse = ResponseCodes.OBEX_HTTP_OK;

        String destination;
        if (mTransport instanceof BluetoothObexTransport)
        {
            destination = ((BluetoothObexTransport) mTransport).getRemoteAddress();
        }
        else
        {
            destination = "FF:FF:FF:00:00:00";
        }
        boolean isWhitelisted =IsWhitelisted(destination);

        try
        {
            boolean preReject = false;

            request = op.getReceivedHeader();
            if (V)
            {
                // Constants.logHeader(request);
            }
            name = (String) request.getHeader(HeaderSet.NAME);
            length = (Long) request.getHeader(HeaderSet.LENGTH);
            mimeType = (String) request.getHeader(HeaderSet.TYPE);

            if (length == 0)
            {
                if (D)
                {
                    Log.w(TAG, "length is 0, reject the transfer");
                }
                preReject = true;
                obexResponse = ResponseCodes.OBEX_HTTP_LENGTH_REQUIRED;
            }

            if (name == null || name.isEmpty())
            {
                if (D)
                {
                    Log.w(TAG, "name is null or empty, reject the transfer");
                }
                preReject = true;
                obexResponse = ResponseCodes.OBEX_HTTP_BAD_REQUEST;
            }

            int dotIndex = name.lastIndexOf(".");
            if (dotIndex > 0)
            {
                extension = name.substring(dotIndex + 1).toLowerCase();
            }


            // Reject policy: anything outside the "white list" plus unspecified
            // MIME Types. Also reject everything in the "black list".
//            if (!preReject && (mimeType == null || (!isWhitelisted && !Constants.mimeTypeMatches(
//                    mimeType, Constants.ACCEPTABLE_SHARE_INBOUND_TYPES))
//                    || Constants.mimeTypeMatches(mimeType,
//                    Constants.UNACCEPTABLE_SHARE_INBOUND_TYPES))) {
//                if (D) {
//                    Log.w(TAG, "mimeType is null or in unacceptable list, reject the transfer");
//                }
//                preReject = true;
//                obexResponse = ResponseCodes.OBEX_HTTP_UNSUPPORTED_TYPE;
//            }

            if (preReject && obexResponse != ResponseCodes.OBEX_HTTP_OK)
            {
                // some bad implemented client won't send disconnect
                return obexResponse;
            }

        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "get getReceivedHeaders error " + e);
            return ResponseCodes.OBEX_HTTP_BAD_REQUEST;
        }         
        int status = receiveFile(destination, name, extension, length, op);
        /*
         * TODO map status to obex response code
         */
        if (status != BluetoothShare.STATUS_SUCCESS)
        {
            obexResponse = ResponseCodes.OBEX_HTTP_INTERNAL_ERROR;
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "MIME TYPE)" + mimeType);
        return obexResponse;
    }
```

I just removed some rejecting codes from the original one.

Also to look at my full code please refer to [my git repository](https://github.com/KYHSGeekCode/BluetoothOPPTelnetServer/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/kyunggi/worker/BluetoothOppObexServerSession.java).

I also thank the contributors to the android project!

Comment: Provided links for the resources you need including compiled apk.

Comment: Be free to accept mine if it works properly :)  It works perfectly on my device.